# Read and update below formatted data of Fire-base in Angular 5 application using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, angularfire2

[image]

I am working on an Angular application. But I am unable to get the data of below formatted (FareDetails) to display in my application using AngularFire2. I have created a service and injected it but I am unable to get any data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Fare} from './fare.model';

@Injectable()
export class FareService {

  FareList: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getFareData() {
    this.FareList = this.firebase.list('/FareDetails');
    return this.FareList;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `valueChanges()` on your AngularFireList to convert it to an observable.
On this Observable you need to subscribe to get the data.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so001

Comment: Can you guide me to convert this object to a table? I am unable to do it